# "재 한구거는 안 좋아요." Can I say it like this?

Tags: grammar, difference

I know I can say "재 한구거는 좋지 않아요", but can I also use 안?

Comment: Please elaborate what you are trying to say and what you are trying to ask

Comment: Yeah, besides some spelling mistakes, it’s totally possible. Adding some adverbs makes it even more natural: “**그다지** 좋지 않아요” / “**별로** 안 좋아요” (“not _that_ good”).

Answer (score 0):

I think you wonder if you can use "안" or not.

1. 제 한국어는 좋지 않아요
2. 제 한국어는 안좋아요.

You can use both of these.

Comment: 2. 제 한국어는 안 좋아요. (Notice the space).

Answer (score 0):

(1) ~지 않아요 (eg: 좋지 않아요) and (2) 안 ~ (eg: 안 좋아요) are two different ways to say "Not X" in Korean

So you have to use form (1) above if you want to use 않, and if you want to use form (2), you have to use 안.

Another post about various ways of negating something in Korean is given here: [What is the difference between -지 않다, -지 못하다, and -ㄹ/을 수 없다?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/181/what-is-the-difference-between-%ec%a7%80-%ec%95%8a%eb%8b%a4-%ec%a7%80-%eb%aa%bb%ed%95%98%eb%8b%a4-and-%e3%84%b9-%ec%9d%84-%ec%88%98-%ec%97%86%eb%8b%a4)